# round off and displaying the values

Tags: java, rounding

I have the following code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.math.*;

public class Testd1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Sum of the specific column!");

        Connection con = null;
        int m = 1;
        double sum, sum1, sum2;
        int e[];
        e = new int[100];
        int p;

        int decimalPlaces = 5;

        for (int i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
            e[i] = 0;
        }

        double b2, c2, d2, u2, v2;
        int i, j, k, x, y;
        double mat[][] = new double[10][10];

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prathi", "root", "mysql");
            try {
                Statement st = con.createStatement();

                ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(
                    "SELECT  Service_ID,SUM(consumer_feedback) " +
                    "FROM  consumer1 group by Service_ID");
                while (res.next()) {
                    int data = res.getInt(1);
                    System.out.println(data);
                    System.out.println("\n\n");

                    int c1 = res.getInt(2);
                    e[m] = res.getInt(2);
                    if (e[m] < 0) {
                        e[m] = 0;
                    }
                    m++;
                    System.out.print(c1);
                    System.out.println("\t\t");
                }
                sum = e[1] + e[2] + e[3] + e[4] + e[5];
                System.out.println("\n \n The sum is" + sum);
                for (p = 21; p <= 25; p++) {
                    if (e[p] != 0) {
                        e[p] = e[p] / (int) sum;
                        //I have type casted sum to get output
                    }
                    BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(e[p]);
                    bd1 = bd1.setScale(decimalPlaces,
                        BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP); // setScale is immutable
                    e[p] = bd1.intValue();
                    System.out.println("\n\n The normalized value is" + e[p]);

                    mat[4][p - 21] = e[p];
                }

            } catch (SQLException s) {
                System.out.println("SQL statement is not executed!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a table named consumer1.After calculating the sum  i am getting the values as follows

mysql> select Service_ID,sum(consumer_feedback) from consumer1 group by Service_
ID;

Service_ID          sum(consumer_feedback) 
       31                           17 
       32                           0 
       33                           60 
       34                           38 
       35 |                         38 
In my  program I am getting the sum for each Service_ID correctly.But,after normalization ie while  I am calculating 17/153=0.111 I am getting the normalized value is 0.I want the normalized values to be displayed correctly after rounding off.My output is as follows

C:>javac Testd1.java

C:>java Testd1
Sum of the specific column!
31

17
32

0
33

60
34

38
35

38

The sum is153.0

The normalized value is0

The normalized value is0

The normalized value is0

The normalized value is0

The normalized value is0

But, after normalization, I want to get 17/153=0.111. I am getting the normalized value is 0. I want these values to be rounded off.

Comment: Posting a very large chunk of code, most of which is irrelevant, then expecting us to be your brain is not going to solicit many answers. I've answered anyway, since you're new.

Comment: @Prathiba - To automatically format your source code when you're posting, select your code and click the button with "0 1 0 1".

Answer (score 1):

```
int e[];
```

...

```
e[p] = bd1.intValue();
```

e is an array of integers. How do you expect the value of an integer to 0.111?

Change e to some type that can hold decimal fractions.

Answer (score 1):

Some other comments:

I think you want to set the following to `0`, since your `e` array seems to be zero based.

```
int m = 1;
```

Local variables in Java don't get initialized to any default value, so it's good practice to initialize variables when you define them:

```
double sum = 0.0, sum1 = 0.0, sum2 = 0.0;
```

Realize that you've hard-coded the size of your `e` array, but your query *could* return a greater number of rows, and your program would crash.

```
int e[] = new int[100];
```

The following code:

```
e[p] = e[p] / (int) sum;
```

...won't do what you want. Here's another view of what you're doing:

```
int = int / (int) double;
```

You're storing the result in an integer variable, so you've already lost the fractional portion of your result before you even get to the following line:

```
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(e[p]);
```